# Render same component for 3 routes

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I want my react router to return  component only when URL matches either of those 3 paths exactly and return an error when it doesn't. How can I shorten this?

```
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Table entries={posts} />} />
        <Route path="/evens" element={<Table entries={posts} />} />
        <Route path="/odds" element={<Table entries={posts} />} />
        <Route ??? element={<ErrorPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
```

Comment: `<Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />` to match anything else that wasn't matched more accurately above it. Is this the issue or question you are asking? If not, it's rather unclear what any issue is or what your question is about.

Comment: Just want to avoid repeating code, i.e. element={<Table entries={posts} />} . AFAIK, path property only allows a string value, so not sure

Comment: Correct. RRDv6 routes take only a string `path` prop. If you need to render the same component on multiple paths you need to render a `Route` for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RRDv6 routes take only a string `path` prop. If you need to render the same component on multiple paths you need to render a `Route` for each.

To make the code a little more ***DRY*** you could try mapping the routes from an array of paths.

Example:

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      {["/", "/evens", "/odds"].map(path => (
        <Route
          key={path}
          path={path}
          element={<Table entries={posts} />}
        />
      )}
      <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Now whether or not this is more readable or maintainable is likely up for debate/opinion. It *is* less repetitive though.